# Change 'Unsalvageable' to 'Recommend Closure' in Review Triage

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review-queues, triage

In the Triage review queue we can filter questions into three categories:

- *Looks OK*: For questions that are well laid-out, and can be answered as-is.
- *Should be improved*: For questions that have small content layout, spelling, or grammar issues. An edit to the question will result in the question being clear.
- *Unsalvageable*: For ***questions that cannot be answered***, or ***should not be answered*** and ***need to be removed***.

In my opinion the 'Unsalvageable' category name doesn't properly suit the action (flagging).

---

Let's have this example scenario:

Bob posts a question about an invalid reading of an integer in C++. The question is formatted perfectly and has no issues *but* is a duplicate of another question.

Bob's question appears in the Triage review queue but as the question is a duplicate, reviewers mark the question as *Unsalvageable* and flag it as a duplicate.

---

In this case marking the question as *Unsalvageable* in order to flag it (without going to the actual question) sounds *wrong* but is in fact the correct path.

Here's a few other occasions where this sounds wrong (assuming each question is laid out brilliantly and has no issues):

- Too Broad
- Off-topic
- Other- **For example asking for a purge of database login details from the Stack Overflow database** (it happens)

I suggest that instead, the 'Unsalvageable' name should simply be replaced with 'Recommend Closure', for example:

[image]

..or perhaps another word, just not *Unsalvageable*.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I would even consider a duplicate question unsalvageable in the first place unless it really is that bad. For everything else, how is "unsalvageable" not an appropriate description?

Comment: @BoltClock then perhaps the 'Duplicate' flag option should be disabled for Triage?

Comment: Instead of "Unsalvageable" or "Other" maybe it should be something like "Vote to Close Immediately"?

Comment: Maybe "Should Be Closed", in keeping with "Should Be Improved"?

Comment: Please don't remove the duplicate flag from triage.  Rapidly flagging duplicates is half the point of triage.

Comment: @Kevin Then what do you suggest, an entirely separate option for duplicates or a flag-like 'Should Be Improved' menu? Actually I think the former is a good idea.

Comment: @BilltheLizard What about those like myself with no VTC privilege?

Comment: You still get the close options from Triage, don't you?

Comment: @BilltheLizard Not sure, I don't think I've ever had them.This is what Triage looks like for me: http://i.imgur.com/lZsrcn7.png http://i.imgur.com/LisHmSG.png.

Comment: What options do you get when you click "it should be closed for another reason..."?

Comment: @BilltheLizard I only have the standard flag options: http://i.imgur.com/6xfpsBf.png. Am I meant to be seeing the close options, too?

Comment: Yes, when you click "it should be closed for another reason..." it should give you more options. It might not be, possibly because you don't have VTC privileges yet.

Comment: Regardless of whether you have the options or not, I see how "Vote to Close" can be confusing in the Triage context. I think I agree with @sphanley that "Should Be Closed" is a better way to phrase this.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Or perhaps 'Recommend Closure'. Updated the question to reflect this as I personally think it's much better than just 'Flag'.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are other types of flags besides close flags.  Unsalvageable covers spam, offensive content, etc.

Comment: @Servy True, perhaps 'Recommend Deletion' then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That replaces a statement on the quality of the question with a specific action for responding to that quality. Which is a much harder decision to make.

#### Not all unsalvageable questions need to be closed.

You'll also encounter:

- Spam
- Blatantly offensive, abusive or nonsensical posts

#### Not all questions that are closed are unsalvageable.

If you're accustom to closing questions, you know that many *can* be salvaged with relatively little effort, if they are only somewhat:

- Unclear
- Broad
- Subjective

...additionally, Duplicates aren't necessarily unsavageable, although Triage has proven itself *very* useful in quickly identifying them.

The same thing applies for Deletion: plenty of salvageable questions get deleted and *should be* deleted, simply because no one cared to salvage them in a reasonable timeframe - that's not a decision to be made in triage, however.